# Customization of pointshape within function fviz_pca from FactoExtra package

Tags: r, pca, ggpubr

I have been struggling to make a change on the default point shape that comes in the output plot within the function `fviz_pca` from the R package `FactoExtra`.

The plot appears with a certain order* of point shapes  which I want to customize.

*The corresponding shapes are respectively 16,17,15,12,0,8

```
    fviz_pca_biplot(PCA, axes = c(1, 2), 
            label="var", col.var = "black", #setas
            geom = "point", pointsize = 2, col.ind=PCADF$groups, 
            addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.95,
            ellipse.type ="confidence", palette = "aaas") + theme_minimal()
```

I tried add to the function:

```
  geom_point(aes(shape = c(19,20,21,22,23,24)))
```

and it returned me a error message:

> Error in geom[1] : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable

Any advice to manage and customize the pointshapes within the function fviz_pca?

Answer (score 7):

We can use `scale_shape_manual()` just like with a `ggplot2` object:

```
library(factoextra)

data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,axes = c(1, 2), 
             label="var", col.var = "black", #setas
             geom = "point", pointsize = 2, col.ind=iris$Species, 
             addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.95,
             ellipse.type ="confidence", palette = "aaas") + theme_minimal()+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,20,21))
```

[image]